# How to request Visa Records from Australian Embassy

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, australia

Is there a way we can request past Visa records or the Visa rejection letter from Australian Embassy?

I applied for an Australia Student Visa in 2008 and my Visa got rejected in 2009. I don't have the rejection letter with me. I was young then and did not even bother to ask the Education consultancy about the rejection letter. My Consultancy managed the communication with Embassy. I did not understand the importance of this at that time. Now the consultancy is closed.

Now I am planning to apply for a UK Dependent Visa and I need help in understanding how to declare my Refusal.

Do I need to enter the exact date of refusal in the UK dependent form? I don't know the exact date.
Can I request the Visa rejection letter from Australian Embassy?

Comment: Thank you. I submitted my inquiry with the local Australian Embassy.

Comment: If you’re still around on TSE, it would be great if you would update on whether you managed to get your records and if so, through which channel, in case of future questions on the same topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you can’t remember the exact date and/or don’t have any paperwork relating to the rejection, you should enter your best ‘guesstimate’ and provide an explanation in your covering letter.

Having said that, if time permits, I would email your local Australian Embassy https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/contact-us/offices-and-locations to ask how to get details of your Australian immigration record. A quick search of the Australian Dept of Home Affairs website didn’t reveal any other way of obtaining the information you need.